# Is iOS 5 iCloud Backup save webkit data for app using the storage of a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, backup, icloud

I have a phonegap iOS app using the sqlite DB of Webkit (through UIWebView), and I wonder if the sqlite data will be saved with iCloud Backup (iOS5). The sqlite data are stored in Library/WebKit folder. In the apple doc, they say:

*The placement of files in your application’s home directory determines what gets backed up and what does not. Anything that would be backed up to a user’s computer is also backed up wirelessly to iCloud. Thus, everything in the Documents directory and most (but not all) of your application’s Library directory.*

But it can say exactly which folder in the library directory are not saved. And I don't know how to access iCloud to check if the directory is saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library/WebKit is included in the backup. With the exception of Library/Caches, everything in the Library directory is backed up.

The data included in an iCloud backup for your app is identical to that included in an iTunes backup, so you can examine the contents by backing up to iTunes and using a tool like [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://supercrazyawesome.com/) to see what's included.

Comment: Thanks, i figure it out by myself after asking the question, but it's good to have a confirmation ;)